# What is Google Cloud's "standard list filter"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I want to see all Datastore export operations. The documentation for Google Cloud Datastore's projects.operations.list states that the [filter parameter](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects.operations/list#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS.filter) is a "standard list filter". What does this mean?

I tried the following:

- `operationType:EXPORT_ENTITIES`
- `operationType:"EXPORT_ENTITIES"`
- `metadata:common:operationType:"EXPORT_ENTITIES"`
- `operationType=EXPORT_ENTITIES`
- `operationType="EXPORT_ENTITIES"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the period to index into objects in the response, like for the similar Compute API [instances.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS.filter):

```
metadata.common.operationType="EXPORT_ENTITIES"
```

I constructed this string by looking at the unfiltered response. It had a `metadata` object with `common` nested inside.